# Get Values of Unique Sentences - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in my indexed document that is a sentence. I intend to find the values of unique sentences across all documents in the index. This field is a "string" field and is analyzed. I have tried the `cardinality` aggregations but it gives me a count of unique sentences, but not the actual unique values. How do I solve this problem?

This is my search query

```
{
   "fields":[
      "incident.name"
   ],
   "aggs":{
      "unique_vuls":{
         "cardinality":{
            "field":"incident.name"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation for that.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I tried the terms aggregation, but it gives me a list of unique words and not the entire sentences that make up the `incident.name` field.

Comment: Yeah, because your 'name' field needs to be not_analyzed or analyzed with the keyword analyzer. Or have the field transformed to a multifield where one of the subfields is not analyzed.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - This worked. Thank you. Ill post the answer for others benefit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update & Answer: Per @AndreiStefan's advice, I re-mapped the field as a `multi-field` and re-indexed the data. Subsequently, I queried using the `incident.name.raw` field and was able to obtain all the unique sentences in the index.

Here's the snippet of the mapping:

```
{
   "name":{                          #incident.name field
      "type":"string",
      "index":"analyzed",
      "fields":{
         "raw":{
            "type":"string",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the snippet of the search query with `terms` aggregation:

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "unique_incidents":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"incident.name.raw"
         }
      }
   }
}
```